# When implementing the 'factory' pattern for a fragment, do you always have to specify arguments, even if they aren't used?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When needing to create a fragment with specific arguments, I understand the need to use the factory pattern that passes in those arguments in a bundle, as opposed to creating non-default constructors, considering they can be torn down and re-created as the system dictates.  What I'm wondering is if you're not passing any arguments, do you still have to create a new bundle for them, or can you just skip that?

i.e. instead of this...

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

Is this allowed?

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {
    return new MyFragment();
}
```

And actually, in those cases where I am ***guaranteed to never need arguments***, is it acceptable practice to not use the factory pattern at all and instead just new up the fragments as needed, or should you still add it for consistency?

As a follow-up, in cases where a factory method is needed, is there a consistent or recommended name for it?  I've seen all of the following:

- new()
- newInstance()
- newFragment()
- create()
- createFragment()
- createInstance()
- createItem()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this allowed?
>
> ```
> public static MyFragment newInstance() {
>     return new MyFragment();
> }
> ```

Absolutely. There's no need to create and assign an empty arguments `Bundle`.

> in those cases where I am guaranteed to never need arguments, is it acceptable practice to not use the factory pattern at all and instead just new up the fragments as needed

Absolutely. The pattern you mention is just a convenience for you (the developer) that also helps to make sure you're always specifying the necessary information. When you don't need any arguments, just invoking the default constructor yourself is perfectly fine.

You could argue that it might be better to always use a `newInstance()` method, so that your team is never confused about whether to use a static factory method or a constructor, but this is a decision you and/or your team should make; there's no rule against using constructors.

> is there a consistent or recommended name for it?

Personally I have seen `newInstance()` much more than the others, but I do not believe there is any defined standard.

Comment: And I agree about the 'not confusing the team' part. I kinda wished Android would force it one way or another for that very reason by making fragment constructors protected, although I get why they don't.